# Sort Laravel collection of objects by object field

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

I am needing to sort a collection of objects based on the object fields. **I have seen numerous similar questions but none of the solutions have worked**. Here's what I have so far.

```
        $activities = collect();
        foreach(request()->user()->currentTeam->users as $user) {
        $activities->push(Activity::where('description', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('properties->name', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->causedBy($user)->latest()->get()->load('causer'));
        }

       $flatActivities = $activities->collapse();

       $sorted = $flatActivities->sort(function($a, $b)
       {
           dd($a->id, $b->id);
           if ($a->id == $b->id) {
              return (0);
           }
           return (($a->id > $b->id) ? -1 : 1);
       });
```

In addition to the sort function I have above, I have tried `sortBy(id)` and `sortByDesc()` none of which did anything.

Right now, since I am querying the activity log of each user, it's ordering based on the `latest` activity of that particular user. Ideally, I would love to be able to do this with my query but I don't see how that's possible since I am grabbing the data per user.

I am able to do this if I convert the collection to an array but due to some other constraints I need to keep it as a collection of objects.

#### Edit

Just to be clear, here's the structure of my data.

```
{
"0": {
    "id": 4740,
    "log_name": "default",
    "description": "Login: Advisor User logged in from 127.0.0.1.",
    "subject_id": null,
    "subject_type": "App\\User",
    "causer_id": 4,
    "causer_type": "App\\User",
    "properties": {
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "name": "Advisor User",
        "action": "login",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-06-05 14:33:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-05 14:33:34",
    "causer": {
        "id": 4,
    }
},
"1": {
    "id": 4737,
    "log_name": "default",
    "description": "Login: Advisor User logged in from 127.0.0.1.",
    "subject_id": null,
    "subject_type": "App\\User",
    "causer_id": 4,
    "causer_type": "App\\User",
    "properties": {
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "name": "Advisor User",
        "action": "login",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-06-05 14:27:58",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-05 14:27:58",
    "causer": {
        "id": 4,
    }
},
"2": {
    "id": 4735,
    "log_name": "default",
    "description": "Login: Advisor User logged in from 127.0.0.1.",
    "subject_id": null,
    "subject_type": "App\\User",
    "causer_id": 4,
    "causer_type": "App\\User",
    "properties": {
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "name": "Advisor User",
        "action": "login",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-06-04 19:26:49",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-04 19:26:49",
    "causer": {
        "id": 4,
    }
},
"3": {
    "id": 4739,
    "log_name": "default",
    "description": "Login: test test logged in from 127.0.0.1.",
    "subject_id": null,
    "subject_type": "App\\User",
    "causer_id": 7,
    "causer_type": "App\\User",
    "properties": {
        "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "name": "test test",
        "action": "login",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-06-05 14:32:55",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-05 14:32:55",
    "causer": {
        "id": 7,
    }
},
}
```

I need to sort, in descending order, by the object id.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the following on your collection:

```
$sorted = $flatActivities->sortBy('order');
```

This will sort it in ascending order by the order field of whatever models you have there.

In case you want to sort them in descending order, do:

```
$sorted = $flatActivities->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true);`
```

Comment: I've already tried using `sortBy`. It doesn't make a difference. I've made an edit to my post just to be clear about the structure of my data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the first answer

```
$sorted = $flatActivities->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true)->values();
```

or

```
$sorted = $flatActivities->sortByDesc('order')->values();
```

need values() function to "The values method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers:"